# SQL The multi-part identifier "AVG.Hours" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to find out the max avg hours that from the department and show out the most highest hour employees name.

However, I do not really understand the question for me; the question want me first to find out which department spend most time in the project then find the employees who in that department has work for all project

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname, MAX(AVG.Hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN Project AS p ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON AS w ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
GROUP BY e.Fname, e.Lname;
```

and get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 161
>   The multi-part identifier "AVG.Hours" could not be bound.

Here is the table and information that insert into

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
    Fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Minit CHAR(1) NULL,
    Lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Sex CHAR(1) NULL,
    Salary DECIMAL(10, 2) NULL,
    Super_ssn CHAR(9) NULL,
    Dno INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (Ssn),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEE FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT 
(
    Dname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Mgr_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Mgr_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTMENT PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn)
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTMENT 
        FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber);

CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS 
(
    Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Dlocation VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT_LOCATIONS PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber, Dlocation),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPT_LOCATIONS_DEPARTMENT FOREIGN KEY (Dnumber) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    Pname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Pnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Plocation VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    Dnum INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROJECT PRIMARY KEY (Pnumber),
    CONSTRAINT UK_PROJECT UNIQUE (Pname),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PROJECT_DEPARTMENT FOREIGN KEY (Dnum) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON 
(
    Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Pno INT NOT NULL,
    Hours DECIMAL(3, 1) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_WORKS_ON PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Pno),
    CONSTRAINT FK_WORKS_ON_EMPLOYEE FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn),
    CONSTRAINT FK_WORKS_ON_PROJECT FOREIGN KEY (Pno) REFERENCES PROJECT (Pnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT 
(
    Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Dependent_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Sex CHAR(1) NULL,
    Bdate DATE NULL,
    Relationship VARCHAR(8) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEPENDENT PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Dependent_name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPENDENT_EMPLOYEE FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn)
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTMENT;

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno) 
VALUES ('James', 'E', 'Borg', '888665555', '1937-11-10', '450 Stone, Houston, TX', 'M', 55000, NULL, 1),
       ('Franklin', 'T', 'Wong', '333445555', '1955-12-08', '638 Voss, Houston, TX', 'M', 40000, '888665555', 5),
       ('Jennifer', 'S', 'Wallace', '987654321', '1941-06-20', '291 Berry, Bellaire, TX', 'F', 43000, '888665555', 4),
       ('Alicia', 'J', 'Zelaya', '999887777', '1968-01-19', '3321 Castle, Spring, TX', 'F', 25000, '987654321', 4),
       ('Ahmad', 'V', 'Jabbar', '987987987', '1969-03-29', '980 Dallas, Houston, TX', 'M', 25000, '987654321', 4),
       ('John', 'B', 'Smith', '123456789', '1965-01-09', '731 Fonden, Houston, TX', 'M', 30000, '333445555', 5),
       ('Ramesh', 'K', 'Narayan', '666884444', '1962-09-15', '975 Fire Oak, Humble, TX', 'M', 38000, '333445555', 5),
       ('Joyce', 'A', 'English', '453453453', '1972-07-31', '5631 Rice, Houston, TX', 'F', 25000, '333445555', 5);

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date) 
VALUES ('Research', 5, '333445555', '1988-05-22'),
       ('Administration', 4, '987654321', '1995-01-01'),
       ('Headquarters', 1, '888665555', '1981-06-19');

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTMENT 
        FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dnumber);

INSERT INTO DEPT_LOCATIONS (Dnumber, Dlocation) 
VALUES (1, 'Houston'), (4, 'Stafford'), (5, 'Bellaire'),
       (5, 'Sugarland'), (5, 'Houston');

INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname, Pnumber, Plocation, Dnum) 
VALUES ('ProductX', 1, 'Bellaire', 5),
       ('ProductY', 2, 'Sugarland', 5),
       ('ProductZ', 3, 'Houston', 5),
       ('Computerization', 10, 'Stafford', 4),
       ('Reorganization', 20, 'Houston', 1),
       ('Newbenefits', 30, 'Stafford', 4);

INSERT INTO WORKS_ON (Essn, Pno, Hours) 
VALUES ('123456789', 1, 32.5),
       ('123456789', 2, 7.5),
       ('666884444', 3, 40.0),
       ('453453453', 1, 20.0),
       ('453453453', 2, 20.0),
       ('333445555', 1, 10.0),
       ('333445555', 2, 10.0),
       ('333445555', 3, 10.0),
       ('333445555', 10, 10.0),
       ('333445555', 20, 10.0),
       ('999887777', 30, 30.0),
       ('999887777', 10, 10.0),
       ('987987987', 10, 35.0),
       ('987987987', 30, 5.0),
       ('987654321', 30, 25.0),
       ('987654321', 20, 15.0),
       ('888665555', 20, NULL);

INSERT INTO DEPENDENT (Essn, Dependent_name, Sex, Bdate, Relationship) 
VALUES ('333445555', 'Alice', 'F', '1986-04-05', 'Daughter'),
       ('333445555', 'Theodore', 'M', '1983-10-25', 'Son'),
       ('333445555', 'Joy', 'F', '1958-05-03', 'Spouse'),
       ('987987987', 'Abner', 'M', '1942-02-28', 'Spouse'),
       ('123456789', 'Michael', 'M', '1988-01-04', 'Son'),
       ('123456789', 'Alice', 'F', '1988-12-30', 'Daughter'),
       ('123456789', 'Elizabeth', 'F', '1967-05-05', 'Spouse');
```

Comment: Some sample data and an expected result would make this question easier to understand. It sounds like you could do this with a `TOP 1` if I'm understanding it correctly, but I am unsure if that's what you mean. e.g. `SELECT TOP 1 e.Fname, e.Lname, AVG(Hours) FROM blah GROUP BY e.FName, e.LName ORDER BY AVG(Hours) DESC;`

Comment: @ Lee David - Please share the table structure and expected output to help you. Currently, the solution shared below by me based on my assumption that either you want to compute average hours or Max hours for each employee. you can use below updated query by me if that is your requirement or  else share what you want to achieve/ expected result.

Answer (score 1):

use the avg functions as stated below

```
SELECT  tab.Fname ,tab.Lname, MAX(avgHours)
FROM
(
    SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname, AVG(Hours) AS avgHours
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
    INNER JOIN Project AS p ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
    INNER JOIN WORKS_ON AS w ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
    GROUP BY e.Fname, e.Lname
) AS Tab
```

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function directly within another aggregate function like that (unless using an `OVER()` clause).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute Max hours of each employee then your query should be like below:

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname, MAX(Hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN Project AS p ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON AS w ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
GROUP BY e.Fname, e.Lname;
```

If you want to compute Average hours of each employee then your query should be like below:

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname, Avg(Hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN Project AS p ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON AS w ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
GROUP BY e.Fname, e.Lname;
```

Comment: in fact the question I not really understand the question is 
find the names of employees who work on *all* the projects controlled by the department which spends most hours on projects.
for me I think that I need to find out the employees who work in all project and need to write by department?

Comment: the above query will give you all the employee who has departure and worked on projects along with max hours spend in all the projects. If you want max hours by each department then you should also include department in the group by, if you want max hours by each project and then you should include the project in the group by. The query you have written giving you an error because avg.hours does not exist. sql trying to find "avg" as table/view name or alias which does not exist. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte ( 
              SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname, AVG(Hours) AS avgHours, d.Dnumber as department
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
    INNER JOIN Project AS p ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
    INNER JOIN WORKS_ON AS w ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber
    GROUP BY e.Fname, e.Lname
             )
select max(avgHours) from cte group by department
```

This common table expression is one other way to obtain your result.